# Can an Indian citizen holding resident visa in UAE with sales designation travel with visit visa to kuwait?

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, kuwait

I have a valid two years resident card in United Arab Emirates, however i have seen that to enter into Kuwait with even visit visa i should have my designation specific(Like Engineer, Doctor etc..). But, in my resident visa of United Arab Emirates my designation is "Sales". Now, if i apply for Visit Visa to Kuwait can i be able to enter into Kuwait if i apply for visa in online and not going to Kuwait embassy.

Answer (score 1):

The [official Kuwait e-visa site](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/) says that your GCC residence document must show one of the specific list of professions.

> Consultants
>   Doctors
>   Engineers
>   Lawyers
>   Judges&Members of Public Prosecution
>   University Teachers
>   Press&Media Staff
>   Pilots
>   System Analysts & Computer Programmers
>   Managers
>   Businessmen
>   Diplomatic Corps
>   University Graduates – Owners, Managers and Representatives of Commercial Companies and Establishments

Based on the information available, it doesn't appear that you can qualify for the e-visa. But "Businessmen" seems very generic to me. Perhaps it has some special meaning on a GCC residence permit, or perhaps it is just general and any sort of businessman would qualify.

If you want to be completely safe, apply for the regular visa from the embassy. If you want to take a bit of a risk, you can try to apply for the e-visa. You might be approved. If you're declined, then you can go back to apply for the regular visa. But the reason this is risky is that even if you are approved, the immigration officers might decide at the border that you didn't qualify, and issue a fine and/or refuse entry. It is up to you to decide whether this risk is worth taking.